# Searching for "|" pipe symbol in XML column in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I am using a script like this to look for a "|" symbol in a XML column no matter where it appears. I know there are pipes in there but the below query gives me empty results

```
SELECT TOP 100 *
FROM 
    [DB].[dbo].[InputData]
WHERE 
    Content.exist('//.[text() = "|"]') = 1
    AND DataFileId = '75d48aed6327'
```

What am I doing wrong? This is the xml content of the column `Content`:

```
<CLAIM version="native">
   <INPUT>
      <HEADER BIRTH_DT="1/1/1941">
         <DIAG_CODES>
            <DX CODE="7234" />
         </DIAG_CODES>
         <CON_CODES>
            <CON_CODE VALUE="M0" />
         </CON_CODES>
         <VAL_CODES>
            <VAL_CODE CODE="A2" AMT="604.03" />
         </VAL_CODES>
      </HEADER>
</CLAIM>
```

Comment: You're missing a `</INPUT>` element in your XML (or is that just a typo in your question?) And also: your sample XML doesn't show any `|` character, either.....

Comment: i am missing </INPUT>. That is just a sample. The XML is very long but there could be a pipe symbol in this tag <LIST> "123|345" </LIST> and few other tags

Comment: @user176047 - Your SQL query is looking for nodes that *equal* `|`, not nodes that *contain* `|`.  Big difference.

Answer (score 2):

Hi was looking the answer and found it here https://stackoverflow.com/a/11738172/1692632

```
DECLARE @xmlTable TABLE (xmlData XML)

INSERT INTO @xmlTable SELECT N'
<CLAIM version="native">
      <HEADER BIRTH_DT="1/1/1941">
         <DIAG_CODES>
            <DX CODE="7234" />
         </DIAG_CODES>
         <CON_CODES>
            <CON_CODE VALUE="M0" />
         </CON_CODES>
         <VAL_CODES>
            <VAL_CODE CODE="A2" AMT="604.03" />
         </VAL_CODES>
      </HEADER>
</CLAIM>
'
INSERT INTO @xmlTable SELECT N'
<CLAIM version="native">
      <HEADER BIRTH_DT="1/1/1941">
         <DIAG_CODES>
            <DX CODE="72|34" />
         </DIAG_CODES>
         <CON_CODES>
            <CON_CODE VALUE="M0" />
         </CON_CODES>
         <VAL_CODES>
            <VAL_CODE CODE="A2" AMT="604.03" />
         </VAL_CODES>
      </HEADER>
</CLAIM>
'

SELECT T.*
FROM @xmlTable AS T
CROSS APPLY T.xmlData.nodes('//@*') as tx(r)
WHERE tx.r.value('contains((.),"|")','bit')=1
```

Also you can try this one as you tried (this gives without duplicates):

```
SELECT TOP 100 *
FROM 
    @xmlTable
WHERE 
    xmlData.exist('//@*[contains(., "|")]') = 1
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT TOP 100 *
FROM [DB].[dbo].[InputData]
WHERE DataFileId = '75d48aed6327'
and charindex('|',Content) > 1
```

Comment: `-1` - This would match on a `|` *anywhere* in the text, not just an XML text value.